# Which one of the sentences is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, difference, grammaticality

Which one of the following sentences is correct, and why?

“I would rather you take care of the children.”

“I would rather **have** you take care of the children.”

Answer (score 1):

Both are acceptable, with possibly different shades of meaning.

> I would rather **you** take care of the children (than anyone else).
>
> I would rather have you take care of the children (than help in any other way).

Comment: The second could also have the implication "while I do something else".